# Derivation of the MINRES method for linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

The MINRES algorithm attempts to solve $A x = b$, where $A$ is symmetric/Hermitian. I am trying to derive the method on my own, but I keep getting nowhere.

Everytime MINRES is mentioned in literature, the same reference is brought up: [C. C. Paige and M. A. Saunders, "Solution of Sparse Indefinite Systems of Linear Equations"](https://doi.org/10.1137/0712047).

This paper, however, is of no help to underestand the method, as the authors use confusing notation, go off on tangents, and never peresent the algorithm in a short and concise manner.

My progress so far is:

- Take $A$ and $b$ and compute matrices $V$ (orthogonal) and $T$ (tridiagonal) using the Lanczos algorithm, such that
  $$ V^\intercal A V = T \quad \implies \quad A V = V T$$
- Write the solution as a linear combination of the columns of $V$:
  $$x = Vy$$
- Rewrite the system as
  $$ Ax = AVy = VTy = b \quad \implies \quad T y = V^\intercal b = \lVert b \rVert e_1$$

Now I'm lost, because the paper suggest to find some auxiliary vector $t$, as well as the inverse of some Cholesky decomposition matrix $L$ and write $x$ in terms of that instead, leading to: $ x = V L^{-1} t $, because somehow $y = L^{-1} t $.

To increase my frustration, when looking on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_residual_method), a completely different (and seemingly much simpler) algorithm is shown that does not require the Lanczos step at all! And this is presented without explanation or references!

Questions:

- How to find $t$ and $L$?
- Do we really need to compute $L^{-1}$? Why not invert $T$ to find $y$?
- How to go from matrix sintax to a recursive formulation that requires minimal memory?
- <s>How is the wikipedia algorithm related to the [original article](https://doi.org/10.1137/0712047)?</s>

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**: I learned now, that the algorithm shown in the wikipedia page is in fact the [Conjugate Residual (CR) method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_residual_method), and not the MINRES method.

Comment: I would love to see some illuminating derivations of this method.

Comment: See _Iterative Krylov Methods for Large Linear Systems_ by Henk van der Vorst.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it now.

##### As a direct method

Take $Ax = b$.

Employ Lanczos algorithm to find $V$ and $T$ such that
$$V^\intercal A V = T \quad \implies \quad A V = V T \,,$$
where $V$ is an orthogonal matrix whose first column is $v_1 = \frac{b}{\lVert b \rVert}$, and $T$ is tridiagonal ($T$ is both upper and lower Hessenberg due to A being symmetric).

Express the solution in therms of a linear combination of the columns of $V$
$$x^* = Vy$$

Rewrite the system:
$$Ax^* = A V y = V T y = b \quad \implies \quad T y = V^\intercal b = \lVert b \rVert e_1$$

Perform a series of Givens rotations on $T$ to obtain its QR decomposition (R is upper triangular):
$$T = QU$$

Rewrite again:
$$T y = Q U y = \lVert b \rVert e_1 \quad \implies \quad Uy = \lVert b \rVert Q^\intercal e_1 $$

Denote $ \alpha = Uy = \lVert b \rVert Q^\intercal e_1 \quad \implies y = U^{-1} \alpha$

Leading to $x^* = V y = V U^{-1} \alpha$.

Denote $P = V U^{-1}$, yielding

$$ x^* = P \alpha = \lVert b \rVert V U^{-1} Q^\intercal e_1$$

##### Critical Remarks

- Note that $U$ is upper triangular but only has 3 (upper) diagonals. Thus, the information needed to generate a new column of $P$ is contained within the respective column of $V$ and two previous columns of $P$. This becomes apparent, if we write $PU = V$. Therefore, rather than computing $U^{-1}$ and then $V U^{-1}$, we can instead generate the columns $P$ sequentially by a short (3 terms) recurrence relationship.
- Note that, while the vector $y$ cannot be found until the whole procedure is completed (all entries depend on the very last one), the vector $\alpha$ can be found sequentially, with the guarantee that previously determined elements are constant (columns of $Q$ are constant).
- Finally, note that $x^* = Vy = P \alpha$, so rather than taking orthogonal steps along the columns of $V$, we can take oblique (but still linearly independent) steps given by the columns of $P$. Steps taken along the columns of $P$ do not need to be revisited (coefficients $\alpha$ do not change).